# calculate the difference between two dates with strtotime

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo how much days are left between a variable and NOW. This is the code

```
$now = date('Y-m-d'); 
$daysleft=  strtotime($starttheproject -$now);
```

`echo 
"Now =".$now.
"<br> Starttheproject =".$starttheproject.
"<br> Daysleft =".$daysleft;`

**Result of echo:**

- Row =2014-10-17
- Starttheproject =2014-10-22
- Daysleft =

**Question:**
How can calculate the number of days, so that the result will be '5'
I've been playing with code like this, with no luck:

```
$daysleft=  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($starttheproject -$now));
```

Comment: check for DateTime::Diff

Comment: when I use this:   $daysleft = abs(strtotime($starttheproject) - strtotime($now));
then the result is 3891600

@AbhikChakraborty
I tried: $daysleft = $starttheproject->diff($now);

Comment: I've checked that post already before posting. The solution was not working in my case. Result was "0 years, 0 months, 0 days"

Comment: [***Looks just fine to me, I get 5 days as expected.***](https://eval.in/207243)

Comment: $starttheproject is a String???,  strtotime($starttheproject) -$now instead  strtotime($starttheproject -$now)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-03-10');
$finish = new DateTime();
$difference = $date->diff($finish);
$difference =$difference->format('%R%a');
if ($difference > 10) {  //if the post is over 10 days old
  echo 'Renew now';
}else{
  echo 'Renew in '.$difference.' days</font>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this code is not working

Comment: Works fine!! only implement it. $date is $starttheproject and $finish is $now